# Confused about threads

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I'm studying threads in C and I have this theoretical question in mind that is driving me crazy. Assume the following code:

```
1) void main() {
2)     createThread(...); // create a new thread that does "something"
3) }
```

After line 2 is executed, two paths of execution are created. However I believe that immediately after line 2 is executed then it doesn't even matter what the new thread does, which was created at line 2, because the original thread that executed line 2 will end the entire program at its next instruction. Am I wrong? is there any chance the original thread gets suspended somehow and the new thread get its chance to do something (assume the code as is, no sync between threads or join operations are performed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work out either way. If you have more than one core, the new thread might get its own core. Even if you don't, the scheduler might give the new thread priority over the existing one. The original thread might exhaust its timeslice right after it creates a new thread.

So that code creates a race condition -- one thread is trying to do work, another thread is trying to terminate the process. Which one wins will depend on the threading implementation, the hardware, and perhaps even some random chance.

Comment: So you say that it could happen that the "main thread" exhausts its time slice right after the call to createThread() is executed, so it doesn't even gets the chance to make the main() method return from its call (despite its return type is void, there is no return instruction)?

Comment: @JanosAudron Correct. And on many implementations, that's more likely to happen than you might think because of the way thread creation is typically implemented. The internal call to create a thread, as it is returning, is often explicitly coded as a pre-emption point. (Though on a typical modern system, the newly-created thread is probably already going to be running on another core.)

Answer (score 0):

If `main()` finishes before the spawned threads, all those threads will be terminated as there is no `main()` to support them.

Calling `pthread_exit()` at the end of `main()` will block it and keep it alive to support the threads it created until they complete execution.

You can learn more about this here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using POSIX pthreads (not clear from your example) then you are right. If you don't want that then indeed pthread_exit from main will mean the program will continue to run until all the threads finish. The "main thread" is special in this regard, as its exit normally causes all threads to terminate.

More typically, you'll do something useful in the main thread after a new thread has been forked. Otherwise, what's the point? So you'll do your own processing, wait on some events, etc. If you want main (or any other thread) to wait for a thread to complete before proceeding, you can call pthread_join() with the handle of the thread of interest.

All of this may be off the point, however since you are not explicitly using POSIX threads in your example, so I don't know if that's pseudo-code for the purpose of example or literal code. In Windows, CreateThread has different semantics from POSIX pthreads. However, you didn't use that capitalization for the call in your example so I don't know if that's what you intended either. Personally I use the pthreads_win32 library even on Windows.

Comment: The question is more general (not particular to any threads implementation) and is more about what happens at a lower level (assembly). Assume there is no sync between threads: no pthread_exit() or wait() or join() calls are performed neither in main() nor inside the newly created thread/s.

Comment: Not really. You can define those semantics arbitrarily. One could easily imagine a thread implementation that would automatically block on process main thread exit until all subthreads exited.

It happens that pthreads chose semantics such that when the main thread exits, all subthreads are terminated.

I frankly don't know what the native Windows threads semantics do in that case.

Comment: To put it a different way: assembly language doesn't say anything about process or thread management. What would you imagine would happen after main exits, in assembly code? Halt the processor(s)? Not on a multitasking system. At that point you expect the OS's process management code to kick in and do some sort of cleanup. That could easily as not include thread sync, thread termination, backgrounding any active threads so they can continue to run, or whatever other useful function you might like to imagine. If you are imagining a single-tasking environment, maybe it does halt :)